# Android MVP, where check internet connection

Tags: android, mvp

I'm implementing MVP pattern on an Andorid App and I have a doubt about where is the **best place** for **checking the internet connection.**
I usually check if there is internet connection before doing any network call.

So, where should I check it in the **Activity** or in the **Presenter**? 
I think the Presenter would be a nice place, so it decides what to do, however I'm not 100% sure If I should place it in the activity and avoid doing a call to the Presenter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I dont think Presenter is a good place. Presenter should ask the new data from the model, like getData(). Presenter should not know whether its from local database or from server. So checking the internet connection at the Presenter will not be a good idea.

If you use the Repository pattern, the Presenter will ask the model/repository to get the data. The model will send the local data to the presenter first. Parallely, it will send server request(if there is network connection) to download new data, and send the new data to the Presenter.

So I think, the network check must be at the Repository/ model. You could have Util class which implements the actual network check code. And call that method from repository, like `AppUtil.isNetworkConnectionAvailable();`

For more info, refer: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/

Comment: thanks for your approach and for the link. I'll double check it!

Comment: Do tell me, if you find some different perspective. :)

Comment: I'll post here if I find something. However there are lots of different approaches, the problem is that depend on the project ones suit better than others. Thanks.

Comment: have you got a solution?

Comment: In this case you won't be able to show Try again dialog to user, which makes him turn internet on and click on try again.

Comment: You can send an error code in the error callback from the Repository to Presenter. And based on the error code, the presenter can choose to show the "No network, try again" message.

Answer (score -1):

### Solution:-


You should check the internet connection availablity in BaseActivity class and then extend that activity is the better practice i think.

I do in my project like this:-

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    return internet.isAvailable();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am doing this but the problem is that the broadcast receiver is too slow and its callback is triggered after the onCraete of the activity.