# Internet check, where to place when using MVP, RX and Retrofit

Tags: android, architecture, rx-java, mvp, retrofit2

I have went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589008/android-internet-check-layer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007994/android-mvp-where-check-internet-connection#) post. So I really agree with the second post that presenter should not be aware of android specific thing. So what I am thinking is putting internet check in service layer.
I am using Rx Java for making network calls, so I can either place the network check before making a service call, so this way I need to manually throw and IOException because I need to show an error page on view when network is not available, the other option is I create my own error class for no internet

```
Observable<PaginationResponse<Notification>> response = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<PaginationResponse<Notification>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super PaginationResponse<Notification>> subscriber) {
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    Call<List<Notification>> call = mService.getNotifications();
                    try {
                        Response<List<Notification>> response = call.execute();
                        processPaginationResponse(subscriber, response);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        subscriber.onError(e);
                    }
                } else {
//This is I am adding manually
                    subscriber.onError(new IOException);
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
```

The other way I though of is adding interceptor to OkHttpClient and set it to retrofit

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                final Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

                Request request = builder.build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
```

Now the 2nd approach is more scalable, but I am not sure it will be efficient as I would be unnecessarily calling service method and call.execute() method.

Any suggestion which way should be used?
Also my parameter for judging the way is

- Efficiency
- Scalability
- Generic : I want this same logic can be used across apps who are following the similar architecture where MVP and Repository/DataProvider (May give data from network/db)

**Other suggestions are also welcome, if you people are already using any other way.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First we create a utility for checking internet connection, there are two ways we can create this utility, one where the utility emits the status only once, which looks like this,

```
public class InternetConnection {
    public static Observable<Boolean> isInternetOn(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return Observable.just(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Other way of creating this utility is, where the utility keeps emitting the connection status if it changes, which looks like this,

```
public class InternetConnection {
    public Observable<Boolean> isInternetOn(Context context) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                        subscriber.onNext(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
                    }
                };

                context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

                subscriber.add(unsubscribeInUiThread(() -> context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)));
            }
        }).defaultIfEmpty(false);
    }

    private Subscription unsubscribeInUiThread(final Action0 unsubscribe) {
        return Subscriptions.create(() -> {
            if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
                unsubscribe.call();
            } else {
                final Scheduler.Worker inner = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread().createWorker();
                inner.schedule(() -> {
                    unsubscribe.call();
                    inner.unsubscribe();
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Next, in your dataSource or Presenter use switchMap or flatMap to check for internet connection before doing any network operation which looks like this,

```
private Observable<List<GitHubUser>> getGitHubUsersFromRetrofit() {
    return isInternetOn(context)
            .filter(connectionStatus -> connectionStatus)
            .switchMap(connectionStatus -> gitHubApiInterface.getGitHubUsersList()
                    .map(gitHubUserList -> {
                       gitHubUserDao.storeOrUpdateGitHubUserList(gitHubUserList);
                        return gitHubUserList;
                    }));
}
```

Note that, we are using switchMap instead of flatMap. why switchMap? because, we have 2 data stream here, first is internet connection and second is Retrofit. first we will take connection status value (true/false), if we have active connection, we will create a new Retrofit stream and return start getting results, down the line if we the status of the connection changes, switchMap will first stop the existing Retrofit connection and then decide if we need to start a new one or ignore it.

EDIT:
This is one of the sample, which might give better clarity https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test/blob/master/app-safeIntegration/src/main/java/tank/viraj/realm/dataSource/GitHubUserListDataSource.java

EDIT2:

So you mean switch map will try it itself once internet is back?

Yes and No, let's first see the difference between flatMap & switchMap. Let's say we have an editText and we search some info from network based on what user types, every time user adds a new character we have to make a new query (which can be reduced with debounce), now with so many network calls only the latest results are useful, with **flatMap** we will receive all the results from all the calls we made to the network, with **switchMap** on the other hand, the moment we make a query, all previous calls are discarded.

Now the solution here is made of 2 parts,

1. We need an Observable that keeps emitting current state of Network, the first InternetConnection above sends the status once and calls onComplete(), but the second one has a Broadcast receiver and it will keep sending onNext() when network status changes. IF you need to make a reactive solution go for case-2
2. Let's say you choose InternetConnection case-2, in this case use switchMap(), cause when network status changes, we need to stop Retrofit from whatever it is doing and then based on the status of network either make a new call or don't make a call.

How do I let my view know that the error is internet one also will this be scalable because I need to do with every network call, any suggestions regarding writing a wrapper?

Writing a wrapper would be excellent choice, you can create your own custom response which can take multiple entries from a set of possible responses e.g. SUCCESS_INTERNET, SUCCESS_LOGIN, ERROR_INVALID_ID

EDIT3: Please find an updated InternetConnectionUtil here https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test/blob/master/app-safeIntegration/src/main/java/tank/viraj/realm/util/InternetConnection.java

More detail on the same topic is here: https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/android-mvp-that-survives-view-life-cycle-configuration-internet-changes-part-2-6b1e2b5c5294

EDIT4: I have recently created an Internet utility using Android Architecture Components - LiveData, you can find full source code here,
https://github.com/viraj49/Internet-Utitliy-using-AAC-LiveData

A detailed description of the code is here,
https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/internet-utility-using-android-architecture-components-livedata-e828a0fcd3db

Comment: Nice! I really appreciate your answer but have few points. Can you tell me more about the last line then decide if we need to start a new one or ignore it, so you mean switch map will try it itself once internet is back?
Also I am satisfied with one thing that I am not making a network call, but two more things, how do I let my view know that the error is internet one also will this be scalable because I need to do with every network call, any suggestions regarding writing a wrapper?

Comment: Updated the response with EDIT2 tag

Comment: Got it, can you do one more edit and explain the unregister of receiver in the InternetConnects class? Sorry for my delayed response.

Comment: Also regarding this "we need to stop Retrofit from whatever it is doing and then based on the status of network either make a new call or don't make a call" switch map will automatically stop the call in case-2, but will it handle to make the call again when internet comes or I think we need to write more code for that?

Comment: If you are looking for some solid code, have look at this https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test, this project uses Case-1 of internet check, but you can have a better understanding on switchMap. There are two examples, in this project, I would recommend going through app-safeIntegration.

Comment: Hello, First of all, thanks for having this discussion, which lead me to actually create a sample code and a dedicated post on the topic, Please go through the edited answer, where I have added a working solution exactly as you needed. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @VirajTank Would you please add the solution in RxJava2 and without Lambda expression?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Here you can find the one with RxJava2, with Lambda, but if you can't use/don't like it, you can replace lambda with anonymous class in Android studio. hope it helps. https://github.com/viraj49/Survive-config-changes/tree/master/internet-reconnect-example