# Android webView: check internet connectivity, continuously, till the HTML is loaded

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android webView application; I need it to show a custom HTML page when the internet is not available. I, also,  want the user, if disconnected from the internet through the process of loading, can see my URL. So I just want to do something that user get my custom page whenever she/he got disconnected.
I searched many answers but I didn't get the right one.

Comment: like add a loop in main till the app is open and loop check for internet method for condition true or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RxJava/RxAndroid to check if internet connection is available or not. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281335/11040422) should provide you with all the codes required to implement. Or, you can use [ReactiveNetwork](http://pwittchen.github.io/ReactiveNetwork/docs/RxJava2.x/#/) and observe `Connectivity` with `observeNetworkConnectivity(context)` method like the following:

```
ReactiveNetwork
  .observeNetworkConnectivity(context)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(
       connectivity -> {
        // do something with connectivity
        // you can call connectivity.state() or connectivity.type(); 
        }
       throwable    -> {
        // handle error here 
        }
   );
```

If you want to implement it using Android Architecture Components like `LiveData`, please go through this [code](https://github.com/viraj49/Internet-Utitliy-using-AAC-LiveData) and for details, this [article](https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/internet-utility-using-android-architecture-components-livedata-e828a0fcd3db)